# CSS working fine on Windows but not loading on smartphone

Tags: html, css

I have run into a problem with css file not loading on mobile phone. I have made a responsive website with different css files for both pc and phone. When i run the website on pc, it works fine and the phone version also works fine. But on phone, neither of the css files are loaded. At the moment i am hosting the website on my PC, till the issues are resolved. I have tried loading the site from local storage on phone but had no sucess.

I have explored all similar posts in the forum, but most were about `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`. I have used every variation of the meta tag mentioned here but none worked. I have tried changing the media tag too, but none seem to work.

The head of the file is pasted below;

````
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
        
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel= "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-device-width: 720px)" href="mobile720.css">

</head>```
````

Comment: The max-device-width property is depricated. Can you try `media="screen and (max-width: 720px)"`. let me know if that works.

Comment: @dhruwlalan thanks for responding, It was a problem with my localhost, I uploaded it on a hosting site and it is now working fine. Thanks.